# VB.NET filtering/grouping a datatable

Tags: linq, datatable, vb.net-2010

**Sample Scenario**

I have a table in a database with the following fields:- SerialNo, GroupNo, Description, Quantity.  At the moment I am cycling around a DataTable which has been populated from an ADO.NET DataSet and I am adding the fields into a List as follows...

```
' Gets the items from the database and created a DataSet
' The DataSet has a named DataTable called MyTable
ds = GetItems 

' Item is an model in my MVC project
Dim Item As Item

' I am creating a List of items...
i As List(Of Item)

For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables("MyTable").Rows
    Item = New Item() With {
        .SerialNo = If(Not IsDBNull(row("SerialNo")), CInt(row("SerialNo")), 0),
        .GroupNo = If(Not IsDBNull(row("GroupNo")), CStr(row("GroupNo")), ""),
        .Description = If(Not IsDBNull(row("Description")), CStr(row("Description")), ""),
        .Quantity = If(Not IsDBNull(row("Quantity")), CInt(row("Quantity")), 0)
    }

    ai.Add(Item)
Next
```

**Requirement**

Instead of getting every row I want to get just the first occurence of every GroupNo and return this result into a List.  For example...

- SerialNo = 1  GroupNo = 1  Description = Item A  Quantity = 100
- SerialNo = 2  GroupNo = 1  Description = Item B  Quantity = 100
- SerialNo = 3  GroupNo = 1  Description = Item C  Quantity = 100
- SerialNo = 4  GroupNo = 2  Description = Item D  Quantity = 100
- SerialNo = 5  GroupNo = 2  Description = Item E  Quantity = 100
- SerialNo = 6  GroupNo = 3  Description = Item F  Quantity = 100

... should actually be modified to return...

- SerialNo = 1  GroupNo = 1  Description = Item A  Quantity = 100
- SerialNo = 4  GroupNo = 2  Description = Item D  Quantity = 100
- SerialNo = 6  GroupNo = 3  Description = Item F  Quantity = 100

I am using Visual Studio 2010 (VB.NET) with .NET 4.0.

I've tried to research various ways but I either come stuck trying to extract all 4 columns doesn't seem to group correctly.  Note: I don't want to modify the query to only return the subset of data.  I need to filter/group it with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just want to take the first `DataRow` of each group to initialize your `Item`:

```
Dim items = From row In ds.Tables("MyTable").AsEnumerable()
            Let GroupNo = row.Field(Of Int32)("GroupNo")
            Group row By GroupNo Into Group
            Select New Item() With {
                .GroupNo = GroupNo,
                .SerialNo = Group.First().Field(Of Int32)("SerialNo"),
                .Quantity = Group.First().Field(Of Int32)("Quantity"),
                .Description = Group.First().Field(Of String)("Description")
            }
```

If you want to copy it into a `List(Of Item)` you only have to call `items.ToList()`.